# Find list of software packages included (pre-installed) in Gitlab docker CI images

Tags: docker, gitlab, continuous-integration

Where do I find a list of software packages included (*the pre-installed packages*) in Gitlab docker CI images?

I usually use the standard `ruby:2.5` image, but I cannot seem to find a list of all packages and softwares/executables that are included in the available build images.

Where is a list of packages included? Or do I always have to test an image in a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file and see if it works?

(*Surely there is a list of packages. Forgive a newbie in the world of CI.*)

Comment: `the available build images` _All_ images are available https://hub.docker.com/search?q= <- and this is only _one_ repository.  It's not feasible to list "all" packages from "all" available build images. `Where is a list of packages included?` Inside the docker image. Run the docker image locally, find out it's package manager/linux distributor, use the package manager to list the packages. `Or do I always have to test` Yes, usually that it how it's done, or you are building your own.

Comment: @KamilCuk thanks! Between the answer below and yours, it's all clear. I suppose it is a lot of packages listed if they were all out there. Suppose most are Linux core packages. Worse things have happened than having to add a line in a `.gitlab-ci.yml` and running a test project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the GitLab docs:  https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#what-is-an-image.

> The image keyword is the name of the Docker image the Docker executor uses to run CI/CD jobs.

> > By default, the executor pulls images from Docker Hub.

> However, you can configure the registry location in the gitlab-runner/config.toml file. For example, you can set the Docker pull policy to use local images.

So, to see the image content you can go to the Docker Hub image page, for example, Ruby: https://hub.docker.com/_/ruby.

And click on a specific Docker Image Tag to see its layers with the steps and the installed packages: https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/ruby/2.5/images/sha256-dde6be82028418fa39afcc712ac958af05e67dcb31879a3bd76b688453fe4149?context=explore.

[image]